# SQL Stored Procedure Entity Framework VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity

i've created a stored procedure (SP) on my MS SQL db 2008. the SP uses temp tables and a cursor. I have trying to access the result set of the SP however in code (vb.net with entity framework) it is showing the function as a datatype of int however this should be datatype of list (of resultsof(the SP)) any ideas what is causing the datatype to show as int and not the list of.

I've updated my db model and no luck.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey Mike! Would you be able to share the ways around it?

Comment: Steve,  I have checked and updated my answer now. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Clear all references to your sprocs in Entity Framework.

Comment out a most of the body of the sprocs. Just leave the parameters and the final select (which you can fake as long as the types are correct)

Add the sprocs to EF hopefully it adds ok. Now recreate the original sprocs, but don't update it in EF.

**Option 2**

Use code first. But that may be too tricky

**Option 3**

Add this to your stored procedure

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

Delete any existing references to the sproc and add it again

This is easier, especially if you keep changing the sproc.

Comment: Hi Steve, had this problem again today, this time I had to use option 1, just too much going on in the sproc for Entitiy Framework, so recreated sproc with just the output, update EF, then put the code back into the sproc